# Проблема с обрезанием символа в регулярном выражении

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть такое регулярное выражение `/(?<!\S)@([^\s]+)[^\(]+\(([^)]+)\)/i`, для превращения строки вида `@user (text)` в `<a href="example.com/user">text</a>`. Но когда строка не содержит пробела перед скобкой, то вместо нужной строки мы получаем `<a href="example.com/use">text</a>` (последний символ обрезается). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое можно исправить, т.е чтобы последний символ не обрезался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```js
var regex = /(^|\s)@([^()\s]+)\s*\(([^()]+)\)/g;
var str = "Text... @user (text) text...  @user2(text2) "; // => <a href="example.com/user">text</a>
console.log(str.replace(regex, '$1<a href="example.com/$2">$3</a>'));
```

Так как блок просмотра назад здесь заменен `(^|\s)`, код будет работать и в FireFox, и в IE. См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/333FDy/1).

**Подробности**

- `(^|\s)` - Подмаска №1 (`$1`): начало строки или пробельный символ
- `@` - символ `@`
- `([^()\s]+)` - 2 (`$2`): один и более символов, отличных от `(`, `)` и пробельных символов
- `\s+` - один  и более пробельных символов
- `\(` - символ `(`
- `([^()]+)` - Подмаска №3 (`$3`): один и более символов, отличных от круглых скобок
- `\)` - скобка `)`

Comment: Я ожидал чутка другого, Т.е на строку `@user(text)` должно быть не `<a href="example.com/use">text</a>`, а `<a href="example.com/user">text</a>`. Но спасибо за ответ

Comment: @MrCreating Так мой код именно это и делает. Ничего не отсекает.

Comment: Да, он работает, ваш фикс с браузерами мне очень помог, спасибо. Но у вас перед `(text2)` стоит пробел, а с ним и так все хорошо. А когда пробела между `@user2` и `(text2)` нет, то он двойку обрежет и будет `user`. Вот, в чем основная проблема

Comment: @MrCreating Если в строке будет `@user2(text2)`, то в результате будет `@user2(text2) `. Ничего не обрезается. Если пробела там может не быть, замените `\s+`на `\s*`, я исправил код.

Comment: Теперь все работает идеально! Спасибо Вам большое!